# nginx proxy_pass to localhost

Tags: nginx, localhost, proxypass

I'm trying to use proxy_pass in nginx to forward requests to another port on localhost like this:

```
location /foo {
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
location /bar {
    rewrite ^/bar/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
location /blah {
    rewrite ^/blah/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.77.56:8080/;
}
```

So only the last one works.  The first two give me a page-unavailable error.
I know the endpoint is working as I can go directly to localhost:8080 and see output I expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[Edit]: Further enlightenment...  It seems the rewrite line has something to do with it.  Using it like I have here seems to work on non-localhost IPs, i.e. it removes /blah from the path and keeps the rest as it sends it to its final destination.  If I remove the rewrite line I can proxy to localhost (of course losing my indented other stuff on the url).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked:

```
location /blah {
    rewrite ^/blah/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$server_addr:8080;
}
```